# Decorator Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I have been looking at the [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator%5Fpattern) design pattern (I am new to the subject of design patterns), and I was wondering,

1. Can a decorator interact with more than one component?
2. If A is a decorator of component B, can A have operations that B does not have?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1.)  Yes
2.)  Yes, that is the main point of a decorator pattern.  To add functionality to the object it is decorating.

[Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Decorator simply adds functionality to the class it decorates. Sorta like icing on the cake. You may decorate more than one component but that sounds more like Facede though I may be wrong. The second question - the wrapper adds functionality but it also can mask it

Comment: I agree, adding functionality doesn't necessarily mean adding new operations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. What else would the decoration be?